# delete soft link which is checked in under SVN

Tags: svn

I have one soft link checked in under SVN, I would like to delete that soft link, how do I do it.

it is like this -

my_link_abc --> ../../dir_1/dir_1/current_dir

I would like to delete my_link_abc which is soft link. I tried with svn delete my_link_abc, but it says 
svn: Use --force to override this restriction
svn: 'current_dir/work_dir_.....' is not under version control

Actually I just wanted to remove that svn checked in link

Can you help me please...Thanks.

Comment: Deleting a link with `svn rm link` works just fine for me.  What version of Subversion are you using?

Comment: Thanks Ben for posting your comment. However it it not working for me. I did not find rm command. I tried with svn delete link, but no success, I have posted the error which I faced. Version which I use - 1.6.11